# Can I use parent field in the new Lightning Email Templates

Tags: lightning-experience, email-template, merge-field

Summer 18 added the features `Lightning Email Templates` and also added support for `Handlebars Template Language` - [HML](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=handlebars_template_language.htm&type=5)

I really hoped that also the ability to add a merged field of a parent object would be available (see [Cross Object Merge Fields in Email Template](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC) idea)

So for example in my email composer I have added with no luck:

{{{Opportunity.Account.Name}}}

{{{Opportunity.Account.Id}}}

I get this error while sending:

```
Hmm. The merge field Opportunity.Account.Id doesn’t look right. Fix the expression and try again.
```

**QUESTION**

Is it possible today with the new features of `Lightning Email Templates` and `Handlebars Template Language` to add a parent merged field?

If it is possible then - how to do it (I don't need the solution of adding formula field for each required field)?

Comment: If it throws error the I guess it don't like that maybe use formula field then